# What does SONAR Error AvoidRepetitiveCallsToPropertiesRule mean?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have this below piece of code, which i always highlighted by SONAR as a MAJOR issue, because of violation  of a rule called with the below message.

> Multiple (3) calls to virtual property 'System.String System.Reflection.MemberInfo::get_Name()'.

And the rule description says

> AvoidRepetitiveCallsToPropertiesRule
>   gendarme : AvoidRepetitiveCallsToPropertiesRule
>   The rule warn if virtual, or unlikely to be inline-able, property getters are called several times by a method. In most cases repetitive calls simply requires more time without any gains since the result will always be identical. You should ignore the reported defects if a different value is expected each time the property is called (e.g. calling DateTime.Now).**

```
private static void OverrideConfigurationValues(ConfigA configa,
            ConfigB configb, ConfigC configc) 
        {
            Type t = configa();

            var properties = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var overriddenvalues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(configa,null);

                if (value != null)
                {
                    overriddenvalues.Add(prop.Name, value);
                }
            }

            Type b  = configb.GetType();
            foreach (var prop in b.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (!overriddenvalues.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    var value = prop.GetValue(b,null);
                    if (value != null)
                    {

                        overriddenvalues.Add(prop.Name, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var overriddenvalue in overriddenvalues)
            {
                var overriden = overriddenvalue;

                foreach (var prop in configa.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.Name == overriden.Key))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(configa, overriddenvalue.Value,null);
                }
            }
        }
```

If the SONAR is complaining about the line **prop.Name** which i have inside the foreach loop? How can i avoid it?

Comment: In the loop, set a temporary variable `string propName = prop.Name;` then use that wherever you have `prop.Name` inside the loop. Repeat for each loop.

Comment: @ron beyer... How does that solve the issue? The value of Prop.Name changes for every iteration in the loop,buy assigning prop.name to a local variable do you think we are avoiding  multiple calls?

Comment: Because that's what SONAR is complaining about, repeated calls to `prop.Name`, storing it in a temporary variable removes the repeated calls to a property. Since you don't expect the property value to change, SONAR is telling you that you should cache the value instead of repeatedly calling it. The performance benefits are negligible and I'd venture to say that the calls really don't cost that much, but if you want to abide by the rule, thats how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[Ron Beyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4798077/ron-beyer)'s comments are proper answers to this question.

So, your code would look like this based on his comments:

```
...
foreach (var prop in b.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var propName = prop.Name;
    if (!overriddenvalues.ContainsKey(propName))
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(b,null);
        if (value != null)
        {
            overriddenvalues.Add(propName, value);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Note that the support of Gendarme rules was dropped in the 3.0 version of the C# plugin.